# Visual Studio 2015 empty code snippets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

I have using Visual Studio 2015 and have installed all available updates. 
When I am typing for/foreach and Tab, I won't get any snippet any more. I have tried the shortcut Ctrl+K, X, then get an empty list for snippets. I have run the repair Visual Studio and tried all suggestions I could find online, but the result is still the same.

**VS screen shot**

[image: VS screen shot]

Comment: The VS snippets are located in "~Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#". Are there .snippet files in that location?

Comment: Yes there are 38 .snippet files in there and code snippet manager also point to this folder.

Comment: I have just tried to import all the files using code snippet manager, then I could select "My Code Snippets" folder or "ASP.NET MVC 4" folder, so I choosed "My Code Snippets" folder. It is working fine now. Not sure why the other folders are not working.

Comment: I'm not certain off of the top of my head, either. Glad you got it working!

Comment: @Nining you should change your comment to an answer. Your solution is the work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said in your comments, the workaround to this problem is to copy all the Visual C# code snippets located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\3082\Visual C#` inside your Code Snippets folder located in `C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Code Snippets`. Another solution or option is to use an external tool like *Visual Assis*t for *Visual Studio*.

Answer (score 0):

After a whole evening not finding an answer I found it in the most simple way:

Inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets there are two folders: 1033 and 3082. Copy the files and folders from 3082 to 1033.

If you have the two folders try to copy and paste them, it worked like a charm for me and I tried "imports" before with no results.

I found this solution here, I want to honor this guy (elmonopascual) but don't have the reputation yet to do so :) --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/36829804/5761877