# Code Snippets are missing VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

A few days ago there was an update to **VS 2015**. I reopen my project, I find the surprise that the code fragments have disappeared.
For me they are quite useful because by simply pressing TAB twice, code is inserted and it was faster to write code.
I do not know whether the new update they have been removed or if I have to add a configuration to appear again.

The version I have is:

> Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 2 14.0.25123.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here. My solution:

Inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets there are two folders: 1033 and 3082. Copy the files and folders from 3082 to 1033. That worked for me!

Comment: Thank you very much my friend; It works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem in VS2017 after importing settings from VS2015.
Solved by complete re-installing VS2017. Import settings still leads to this bug though.